# Accessing Azure web sites from Visual Studio

Tags: azure

I am currently having a problem attempting to access my Azure websites from Visual Studios. I have connected VS to Azure under the Windows Azure node in server explorer, I can access all of the other services that Azure provides, but when I attempt to refresh the Web Sites node, the following error pops up.

"Subscription Pay-As-You-Go: A security token exception occurred for the received JWT token. The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="A security token exception occurred for the received JWT token"'."

Any ideas?

Comment: Visual Studio restart?

Comment: Did it work before? Try a restart as trailmax said, or just sign in again using the azure symbol on Server Explorer menu

Comment: It never worked before and the restart didn't work either. I may need to look into other forms of remote debugging.